# Automatizar Wifite en Raspberry pi

Tags: bash, raspberry-pi, raspbian, wifi

Estoy programando un script en bash para raspberry pi que al encender ejecute un wifite automatizado y después copie los resultados a un usb.

Estoy utilizando esto:
`sudo wifite -i wlan1 -p 30 --dict /mnt/USB_DEVICE/dic.txt --kill`

La cosa es que en cuanto al diccionario con la potencia de mi raspberry va muy mal ¿Existe un argumento en wifite para que siga capturando Handshake y PMKID pero que no pruebe con ningún diccionario?

Un Saludo.

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo resolví tengo que utilizar
`--dict none`